# Request was made to the incorrect endpoint

Tags: marketing-cloud, c#

I added a refernce of ParenerAPI in my projects.
and calling SoapClient by passing its user name and password.

But I am getting an error " Request was made to the incorrect endpoint."

Is there any token I would have to pass.

Answer (score 7):

You need to check what location your MC instance is on. Find this in the URL  mc.[ ].ExactTarget.com

Use the matching endpoint connection your development environment:

S1 Instance

https://webservice.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx

S4 Instance

https://webservice.s4.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx

S6 Instance

https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx

S7 Instance

https://webservice.s7.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx

Comment: @Robin - Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

I believe the endpoints have changed. I can't post more than two links, but I had to use https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl on an s6 instance. If any of the endpoints in Kelly J Andrews' answer don't work, try changing the Service.asmx to etframework.wsdl